# jQuery v 1.1x changing value of select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery v1.10.2. I need to change the value of a select drop down. I'm using the same js file for both mobile and desktop view (both have different html files). These are the two approaches I've tried to change the value of drop-down:

```
 $('#cType').val('visa');
 $("#cType").prop("selectedIndex", 1);
```

it works fine for the desktop and changes the value, but for mobile it doesn't work. For mobile as well as desktop this is the HTML code I'm using:

```
 <div class="cTypeContainer">
     <label for="cType"><span class="red">&#42;</span>Card Type</label>
      <select name="cType" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" id="cType">
              <option>Select</option>
              <option value="visa">Visa</option>
              <option value="master">Master Card</option>
              <option value="discover">Discover</option>
              <option value="amExpress">American Express</option>
       </select>
 </div>
```

I don't know why it isn't working for mobile. I'm using jQuery mobile, do you think it could possibly intefering with its working?

Comment: It's working fine for me in mobile Chrome (https://jsfiddle.net/q7rhxnhn/2/). Could it be the particular mobile browser you are using or some other conflicting code?

Comment: One thing I've observed is that if don't include the `jquery.mobile.custom.structure.css` file, it starts working fine. I don't know why this CSS file is causing a JS problem. It is a very long jQuery created file, so its really difficult for me pin-point what line is causing this code to break.

Comment: I further debugged it, and found out the value is being changed, its just jQuery mobile is setting the styles in such a way that only the first value is being shown in the visible area.

Comment: My best guess is something else is causing the conflict but it's hard to say for sure. When I include the main jQuery Mobile CSS file, and the one you referenced, in the fiddle it still works for me (https://jsfiddle.net/q7rhxnhn/4/).

Comment: Ok cool, our posts crossed and I just saw yours. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Thanks Mike. But I'm still figuring out how to fix the CSS issue which is causing this

Comment: Sorry, I can't replicate it. Since it seems to be a CSS issue, could there be other styles conflicting? When I open my last fiddle on my phone it works as expected.

Comment: I changed the JS code to this and it worked like a charm: `$('#cType').val('visa').selectmenu('refresh');`

Comment: All it does is basically refreshes the styling to show the dynamically selected value. Thanks for help though Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the JS code to this and it worked like a charm:

```
 $('#cType').val('visa').selectmenu('refresh');
```

All it does is basically refreshes the styling to show the dynamically selected value.